# why transfering speed of MQTT is so low

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am testing a MQTT module for my c++ program, i use it to transfer image to my subscribers (i know this sounds silly), my image size is around 1MB, so it's not really big compares to maximum data size that MQTT can handle (256MB). Everything worked just fine except the transferring speed was super low! while my bandwidth is around 40mbps, the MQTT module just uses 8mbps to transfer.
So can anyone explain for me whether the problem comes from the MQTT protocol itself or it comes from my RabbitMQ server? and how can i improve the speed?

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit). Your use of *"1mb"* implies 1 millibit. Thank you.

Comment: You need to describe in a lot more detail the actual layout of the system you are using to test. But also you  need to explain how you are measuring things as well. At the moment there is no where near enough information for anybody to be able to help here.